# Binary Search for an item in a dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm

Hi I have a problem that I need to solve

The requirements are that I have to use `Binary Search Algorithm` to do this.

I have a dictionary as such:

```
inven = {1 : ["Lettuce", "Fresh Cut Lettuce", 1.30, 1000, False],
             2 : ["Apple", "Red big and round", 1.20, 1000, False],
             3 : ["Orange", "Orange big and round", 1.10, 1000, False],
             4 : ["Peach", "Pink big and round", 1.50, 1000, False],
             5 : ["Pear", "Green big and semi round", 1.30, 1000, False],
             6 : ["Plum", "Red small and round", 0.60, 1000, False]}
```

So the keys of this dictionary are `1,2,3,4,5,6` and the values are the lists that the key belongs to.

I want to use the `Binary Search Algorithm` to find the `key` which the value `"Orange"` belongs to.

I this possible ? Also if it's not possible, please direct me to an `Algorithm` that can solve this for me. Please I know I can just run a `for` loop and settle this issue but it's a requirement that I use an algorithm.

Comment: Doesn't seem like binary search even makes sense here. How do you tell if a given trial key is too big for "Orange" or too small? Are you guaranteed that the first items in the list are in alphabetical order with respect to the keys? If so -- you should say so since that is an important piece of the puzzle. Without an assumption like that, it would be impossible.

Comment: @JohnColeman apparently they aren't - or rather, they would be if not for "Lettuce".

Comment: Doing a binary search directly on that data structure is not possible, though doing a binary search on `sorted([(v[0],k) for k,v in inven.items()])` is possible. That involves a linear pass over the data, as well as a sort, to set up the data structure, after which the original keys can be looked up by the first element of the value in `O(log n)`. This isn't a very good idea, though, since if you are creating a new data structure to search over -- just create a new dictionary: `{v[0]:k for k,v in inven.items()}`

Answer (score 0):

With these keys, you **can't** use binary search, but if you use correct sorted keys, you will be able to apply any searching algorithms as you want.

You can get real keys by calculating each word value, in Python, there is a function called [`ord`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_ord.asp) which converts the character to an int value based on ASCII/UNICODE table. So you can calculate your keys using a function like this :

```py
def key_calculator(word: str) -> int:
    """
    This function converts any string to integer key. 

    pseudocode: 
        key_value = 0
        for each character in the string: 
            key_value += (character index) + (character value)
    """
    # init key_value
    key_value = 0
    # itarate in word length range
    for i in range(len(word)):
        # add the character index with the character value.
        # convert the letter to lower to avoid case sensitivity.
        key_value += i + ord(word[i].lower())
    # return the key
    return key_value
```

Now you can calculate each word key using the function :

```py
inven = {key_calculator(value[0]): value for _, value in inven.items()}
```

This will give us this dict as a result :

```py
inven = {
    779: ["Lettuce", "Fresh Cut Lettuce", 1.3, 1000, False],
    540: ["Apple", "Red big and round", 1.2, 1000, False],
    651: ["Orange", "Orange big and round", 1.1, 1000, False],
    523: ["Peach", "Pink big and round", 1.5, 1000, False],
    430: ["Pear", "Green big and semi round", 1.3, 1000, False],
    452: ["Plum", "Red small and round", 0.6, 1000, False],
}
```

The last step is to sort the dict based on the keys :

```py
# sort inven dict keys 
sorted_keys = sorted(inven.keys())

# sort inven dict based on sorted_keys
inven = {key: inven[key] for key in sorted_keys}
```

This will give us sorted dict as a result :

```py
inven = {
    430: ["Pear", "Green big and semi round", 1.3, 1000, False],
    452: ["Plum", "Red small and round", 0.6, 1000, False],
    523: ["Peach", "Pink big and round", 1.5, 1000, False],
    540: ["Apple", "Red big and round", 1.2, 1000, False],
    651: ["Orange", "Orange big and round", 1.1, 1000, False],
    779: ["Lettuce", "Fresh Cut Lettuce", 1.3, 1000, False],
}
```

Now you can use any searching algorithm to find a word with these steps :

- convert the target word to a key using `key_calculator` function.
- use search algorithm such as binary search.

**OR**

You can access any key randomly using this syntax `inven[key_calculator('Orange')]`.